# Message controller

Tags: iphone, sms

can i check that user is sending sms, or cancel composed message ,
in my application when it is running in background ....
help will be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, assuming this is not a jailbroken phone, you cannot interfere with the operation of other applications.